# GraphQL response ERROR "URLSearchParams is not defined"

Tags: express, graphql

those are the dependencies I'm using

```
"dependencies": {
"express": "^4.16.3",
"express-graphql": "^0.6.12",
"graphql": "^0.13.2",
"lodash": "^4.17.10"
```

}

here is my [schema.js](https://pastebin.com/0UWZLu0a) file looks like

here is the code inside my [server.js](https://pastebin.com/bgYSqKHn) file

and I recieve this error [image]

Comment: copy/paste error ;)
probably need sth like `return _.find(user, {id:args.id});`  - you can find element in array without lodash

Comment: Maybe your browser does't support `URLSearchParams` https://caniuse.com/#search=URLSearchParams

Comment: thanks @xadm you are right I had used 'URLSearchParams instead of 'user' problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lodash library find methods first parameter is the data source. so `URLSearchParam` is mistakenly typed. be careful about auto completions of some IDEs provide. so they may fill incorrect data as you type.

using a  good JavaScript linter can point you that problem. I do recommend eslint.

in this situation the data source is the variable `users` so replacing `URLSearchParam` with users solved this problem.

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue. Here's how I managed to fix it:

```
const { URLSearchParams } = require('url');
global.URLSearchParams = URLSearchParams;
```